# How to customize link from http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/logout/complete

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have multiple azure web apps that use the same proxy. 
The have the following adresses: 
  mysite.azurewebsites.net/**env1**
  mysite.azurewebsites.net/**env2**

When I call mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/logout it redirects me to mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/logout/complete which  displays this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44953.jpg

Actually, the link behind WEBSITE (from image) is mysite.azurewebsites.net/ but I want to be generated depending on environment where logout is called.

For example mysite.azurewebsites.net/env1

Answer (score 1):

You could configure it like below, it will redirect you to `mysite.azurewebsites.net/env1/index.html` page.

```
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=/env1/index.html
```

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#sign-out-of-a-session).